# How many ways can any size group be chosen from a group of N distinct objects?

Tags: combinatorics

For a specific example, suppose I had 3 objects. I could form groups of size 1, 2, or 3. For those sizes, I could form 3, 3, and 1 distinct groups, respectively. This gives a total of 7 distinct groups that can be formed.

Is there a nice, simple formula for computing such a thing?

My instinct tells me that it is probably the sum of the nth row of pascals triangle less 1 since 1, 3, 3, 1 is the 3rd row. And if we counted the null group as a distinct group it would have that missing 1. But even if it is, does that reduce to a "nice" formula?

Comment: It is $2^n - 1$.

Comment: And if you do count the null group, $2^n$.

Comment: @Nick Why are you answering in the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each object, you either include it or you don't. This means you have $3$ choices to make, each with $2$ options. The number of different results is $2^3$ (including the empty case, choosing none of them). This easily generalizes to $2^n$ if you have $n$ objects.

If you specify the number of objects you want to choose first (like you did), then the numbers you get are all picked out of the $n$th row of Pascal's triangle (where the lone 1 at the top is the 0th row). You got $1,3,3,1$, which we recognize as the third row.

Comment: Of course! I was definitely making that more complicated than it needed to be.